# Objective-C Tab view controller move tab bar to top

Tags: ios, objective-c

I create a tabviewcontroller in story board, I'm using Objective-C.

How can I move the position of the tab bar to the top?
I found this code in swift how can it write it in Objective-C?

okay! cool.

Are you experienced in swift?
do you know how can i write this in Objective-C?

Swift3: I achieve this by creating a custom class for UITabBarController:

```
class CustomTabBarController: UITabBarController {

    @IBOutlet weak var financialTabBar: UITabBar!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // I've added this line to viewDidLoad
        UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.size.height
        financialTabBar.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y:  
        financialTabBar.frame.size.height, width: 
        financialTabBar.frame.size.width, height: 
        financialTabBar.frame.size.height)
    }
```

Comment: @BhaumikSurani Thank you for your edit. Just note that it's preferred to use markup syntax whenever possible, and `<br/>` can be replaced by two spaces followed by a new line.

Answer (score 0):

There's no supported way to do that with `UITabBarController`.

If you want a tab bar at the top of the screen, you'd have to build this yourself, or use an open source implementation.

You may find something [here](https://www.cocoacontrols.com) but there are other implementations (on GitHub etc.).

Having the tab bar at the top is an Android thing. On iOS it's always been at the bottom.

It's important to consider that all important apps (including those from Apple) have the tab bar at the bottom. Putting it at the top would mean that your app immediately feels weird for iOS users.

Comment: mm really ? not even programmatically?

Comment: No, it's not supported and never has. It's an Android thing.

Comment: Thanks! i found this in swift, but if do it itunnes connect can reject the app right?

Comment: No, I don't think the app will be rejected.

Comment: okay! cool. Are you experienced in swift? do you know how can i write this in objetive-c  ? i edit the question the code is above. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you are satisfied with your swift version then below is the translated objective-c code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{

    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.tabBar.frame = CGRectMake( 0, [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarFrame.size.height, self.tabBar.frame.size.width, self.tabBar.frame.size.height);

}
```